# How to solve an equation with an inequality limiting the infinite solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The inequality $0 < x+y \leq 60$ and the equation $17x+29y=1222$. How do you find x and y other than bashing?

Edit: I forgot to mention x and y are integers

Comment: Just find all solutions $(x,y)$ of this linear Diophantine equation. Then add. As a hint, you can start with one solution $(x,y)=1222\cdot (12,-7)$, by the Euclidean algorithm. All solutions  arise by adding the ones for the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Have you forgotten to mention that x and y must be integers (or perhaps positive integers)

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes, there is a reason. But even better, the OP confirmed it now.